# Python Build Problem on Mac OS 10.6 / Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, gcc, build, 32-bit

I'm encountering a build problem for Python 2.6.4 on Snow Leopard.

- Mac OS X 10.6
- Yonah CPU, **32-bit**
- gcc-4.2.1

---

**Update I**

Solved by removing all non-standard includes and libraries from CFLAGS (there happened to be a `uuid/uuid.h` in there ...). Still, it compiled *despite* the error describe below, with `/usr/include/hfs/hfs_format.h:765` being a hot spot. For the curious or resourceful, the source file in question:

```
$ cat /usr/include/hfs/hfs_format.h
...
748 #include <uuid/uuid.h>
749 
750 /* JournalInfoBlock - Structure that describes where our journal lives */
751 
752 // the original size of the reserved field in the JournalInfoBlock was
753 // 32*sizeof(u_int32_t).  To keep the total size of the structure the 
754 // same we subtract the size of new fields (currently: ext_jnl_uuid and
755 // machine_uuid).  If you add additional fields, place them before the
756 // reserved field and subtract their size in this macro.
757 //
758 #define JIB_RESERVED_SIZE  ((32*sizeof(u_int32_t)) - sizeof(uuid_string_t) - 48)
759 
760 struct JournalInfoBlock {
761         u_int32_t       flags;
762         u_int32_t       device_signature[8]; // signature used to locate device.
763         u_int64_t       offset;        // byte offset to the journal on the device
764         u_int64_t       size;          // size in bytes of the journal
765         uuid_string_t   ext_jnl_uuid;
766         char            machine_serial_num[48];
767         char            reserved[JIB_RESERVED_SIZE];
768 } __attribute__((aligned(2), packed));
769 typedef struct JournalInfoBlock JournalInfoBlock;
...
```

I'm leaving the question open, since the build yielded too much warnings and this error and still puzzles me a bit ...

**Update II**

To get rid of the warnings regarding the deployment target, I edited the `Makefile` before compilation:

```
$ cat Makefile
...
126 MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 # => 10.6
...
```

---

**Original Question**

When trying to build Python 2.6.4 from source, I run into an error:

```
$ uname -v
$ Darwin Kernel Version 10.2.0: Tue Nov  3 10:37:10 PST 2009; \
    root:xnu-1486.2.11~1/RELEASE_I386

$ cd ~/src/Python-2.6.4
$ ./configure --enable-universalsdk=/ --prefix=$HOME
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
...
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... i386
...
checking for OSX 10.5 SDK or later... no   // <- But I have XCode + the SDKs installed?
...

$ make
...

...
/usr/include/hfs/hfs_format.h:765: error: \
    expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘uuid_string_t’
```

It seems to root in `Python/mactoolboxglue.c`. Hints welcome!

---

Also I get a lot of warnings of these kinds:

```
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for \
Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
gcc -c -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /  -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g \
-fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include  \
-DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Objects/structseq.o  Objects/structseq.c
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
             from /usr/include/math.h:28,
             from Include/pyport.h:235,
             from Include/Python.h:58,
             from Objects/structseq.c:4:
```

Comment: `/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for \
Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.`  Those errors are caused by the Python ./configure script setting MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 10.3 by default.  See my answer for how to get rid of those.

Comment: Rather than editing the makefile, do `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6` prior to running `./configure`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `--universal-archs=32-bit` to the `configure` arguments.

EDIT: You may also need to set environment variable `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6` and explicitly use the 10.6 SDK:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
./configure --universal-archs=32-bit --enable-universalsdk=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk ...
```

There are still some configure issues with building Python on 10.6.  If you re-use the build directory, make sure you clean out all of the cached files that previous runs of `configure` may have left behind.

BTW, if you just need a 32-bit version, you *could* use the 2.6.4 OS X installer from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/).

Comment: configure: error: unrecognized option: --dep-target=10.6 // however I found the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 setting in the Makefile; changed it, and the output looks much nicer now; thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I posted in haste. --dep-target is an argument to the installer build script, not configure. Yes, setting the environment variable before calling configure is the right thing to do.  Fixing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you aren't the only one running into this error:

Not sure if this has the same root cause :

http://trac.macports.org/ticket/21282

Scroll down to the end comments,which seem to indicate a positive outcome. (repeated here for convenience):

...//Quote from trac.macports.org:

"try to rename, move or delete /opt/local/include/uuid/uuid.h"
...//End Quote